# Adding icon to Bootstrap tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may seem trivial, but I am trying to add an icon to a bootstrap tab but I'm having style issues.

Looking for a CSS solution with the following:

1. Icon must float to the right of the link.
2. CANNOT put the icon inside the anchor tag, they must remain at same level.

   ```
   <a></a><i></i>
   ```

   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm51ggL1/)

If anyone can solve this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because Bootstrap styles the `a` inside the tab `li`, you must then redesign the tab to apply the style not to the `a` but to the `li`.

If you can't do that, then you should wrap the icon inside the `a`.

You can try add:

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your `a` inside the `li` tag.

```
nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```